# "eval" for Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, cordova, eval

Does a method like `eval` exist in Objective-C as in Javascript, Ruby, PHP, or Python?

I use PhoneGap and I want to create a window which is specific for each of my projects, and I can't use an HTML file. So I want to call a method from JavaScript and, with one of the arguments being Objective-C code to be interpreted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, there is no "eval" method in Objective-C, and the iPhone license specifically prohibits interpreted code. You can specify a xib/nib file by name, however.

Comment: This should be updated;  the iOS terms now allow for the embedding of interpreters, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString *returnOfJavascriptExecution = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"[your javascript code]"];
```

Comment: No, I want to do the opposite, evaluate OC from JS

Comment: It may not be the right answer to the question asked, but so stoked with that line of code. So helpful!