# Evaluating strings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In Ruby, I was able to execute strings as code like

```
eval("print 5")
```

Is it possible to do exactly the same in Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550897/how-to-eval-objective-c-code-in-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Objective-C is a compiled language.  To evaluate strings like that, there would have to be a compiler embedded in the runtime, and there isn't.

There is a *limited* form of executing strings using methods like`-performSelector` and `valueForKey:` and `NSInvocation`.

Comment: So, if i want to make an app for compiling co code from iOS app, what would be possible best way ? Already there are many apps on appstore.

Comment: You either have to include an interpreter or a compiler in your app. Or you can probably leverage the Webkit Javascript interpreter, if you don't mind Javascript.

Comment: So, can i compile my C code with a local JS file (which return eval result) from app ? or i have to use it from server ? please, elaborate or give me some link to get help. I am going to dev an app regarding this function.

Comment: @JamshedAlam It would be better if you authored a question rather than ask in the comments here, then more people will see it and answers can be written more easily.