# how to solve a conditional equation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I want to solve a conditional equation in iOS:

The equation I get from database is in NSString format, for example:

```
if((height > 0), (weight+ 2 ), ( weight-1 ) )
```

As per our understanding, if I parse the above string and separate`height>0`condition, it will be in the `NSString` format. But to evaluate it how do I convert the string to a conditional statement?

Once the conditional statement is obtained the equation can be solved by converting it to a ternary equation as follows:

```
Bool status;

NSString *condition=@” height>0”;

If(condition)    //But condition is treated as a string and not as a conditional statement.
{
    status=True;
}
else
{
    status=False;
}

Return status ? weight+ 2 : weight-1;`
```

Also the equations can dynamically change, so they cannot be hard coded. In short how do I solve this equation which I get as a `NSString`.

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Are you working with live data in existing format, or you can use any format you want?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550897/eval-for-objective-c-code

Comment: In any ways `height` and `weight` will not be the variable to to compare.

Comment: Hey Tia, we get equations from the webserver which can be updated. However they will be in the same format. A few equations that we get are as follows:

Eg 1. if((height > 0), ( weight / ( height / 100 ) ^ 2 ), ( -1 ) )

Comment: What are the values of the variables in the equation? How do you get those?

Comment: use componentseperatedbystring:@">". get last object.make it int. then compare

Comment: @Amar : these are th float values stored in database

Comment: You either need to write an interpreter or "steal" one from somewhere.  I advise theft, since writing your own is quite difficult and full of pitfalls.  Parsing is only the start -- maybe 10-15% of the job.

Answer (score 5):

DDMathParser author here...

To expand on [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585241/115730), here's how you could do it entirely in DDMathParser.  However, to parse the string as-is, you'll need to do two things.

First, you'll need to create an `if` function:

```
DDMathEvaluator *evaluator = [DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator];
[evaluator registerFunction:^DDExpression *(NSArray *args, NSDictionary *vars, DDMathEvaluator *eval, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    if ([args count] == 3) {
        DDExpression *condition = [args objectAtIndex:0];
        DDExpression *resultExpression = nil;
        NSNumber *conditionValue = [condition evaluateWithSubstitutions:vars evaluator:eval error:error];
        if ([conditionValue boolValue] == YES) {
            resultExpression = [args objectAtIndex:1];
        } else {
            resultExpression = [args objectAtIndex:2];
        }
        NSNumber *result = [resultExpression evaluateWithSubstitutions:vars evaluator:eval error:error];
        return [DDExpression numberExpressionWithNumber:result];
    }
    return nil;

} forName:@"if"];
```

This creates the `if()` function, which takes three parameters.  Depending on how the first parameter evaluates, it either evaluates to the result of the second or third parameter.

The other thing you'll need to do is tell the evaluator what `height` and `weight` mean.  Since they don't start with a `$` character, they get interpreted as functions, and not variables.  If they started with a `$`, then it would be as simple as evaluating it like this:

```
NSString *expression = @"if(($height > 0), ($weight+ 2 ), ( $weight-1 ) )";
NSDictionary *variables = @{@"height" : @42, @"weight" : @13};
NSNumber *result = [expression evaluateWithSubstitutions:variables evaluator:evaluator error:nil];
```

However, since they *don't* start with a `$`, they're functions, which means you need to tell the evaluator what the functions evaluate to.  You could do this by creating functions for both `height` and `weight`, just like you did for `if`:

```
[evaluator registerFunction:^DDExpression *(NSArray *args, NSDictionary *vars, DDMathEvaluator *eval, NSError **error) {
    return [DDExpression numberExpressionWithNumber:@42];
} forName:@"height"];
```

Alternatively, you could make it a bit more dynamic and use the `functionResolver` block of `DDMathEvaluator`, which is a block that returns a block (woooooo) and would look like this:

```
NSDictionary *values = @{@"height": @42, @"weight": @13};
[evaluator setFunctionResolver:^DDMathFunction(NSString *name) {
    DDMathFunction f = ^(NSArray *args, NSDictionary *vars, DDMathEvaluator *eval, NSError **error) {
        NSNumber *n = [values objectForKey:name];
        if (!n) { n = @0; }
        return [DDExpression numberExpressionWithNumber:n];
    };
    return f;
}];
```

With those two pieces in place (registering `if` and providing the values of `height` and `weight`), you can do:

```
NSString *expression = @"if((height > 0), (weight+ 2 ), ( weight-1 ) )";
NSNumber *result = [expression evaluateWithSubstitutions:nil evaluator:evaluator error:nil];
```

... and get back the proper result of `@15`.

(I have plans to make `DDMathParser` allow unknown functions to fall back to provided variable values, but I haven't quite finished it yet)

Comment: I like the start of the answer! :-)

Comment: How to approach in case an equation has a function call Ex: `if(xyz==0, if(abc<0, 270, 90), atan(xyz/abc)*180/_pi)`?

Comment: @Amar as long as you define what `_pi`, `xyz`, and `abc` all are, that'll work just fine.  `atan` is a built-in function.  (But if you called it `pi` instead of `_pi`, then you wouldn't need to define it.  [`pi` is also a built-in function](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Built-in-Functions).

Comment: I am getting error No visible interface for DDMathEvaluator declares the selector evaluateExpression:withSubstitutions.
I looked in DDMathEvaluator.h, no expression like "evaluateExpression:withSubstitutions".

Comment: @SagarJadhav whoops, sorry about that. That's code I haven't pushed yet. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry but when 
NSString *expression = @"if((height > 0), (weight+ 2 ), ( weight-1 ) )";
NSNumber *result = [expression numberByEvaluatingString];
in above equation numberbyEvaluatingString not found error

Comment: @SagarJadhav same issue as before... :P

Comment: @ Dave DeLong: Hi I am doing as given below, still I am getting zero output. So please let me know where I am doing wrong. 

NSString *expression = @"if((height > 0), (weight+ 2 ), ( weight-1 ) )";

    DDExpression *resultExpression = [DDExpression variableExpressionWithVariable:expression];
    NSDictionary *variables = @{@"height" : @42, @"weight" : @13};

      NSNumber *result = [resultExpression evaluateWithSubstitutions:variables evaluator:evaluator error:nil];

Comment: @ Dave DeLong: Hi Dave first of all thanks for your imediate response.
 Can You tell me how to solve this equation: @"sqrt(x^2 + y^2 )";

Comment: @SagarJadhav your first one is wrong; don't create a variableExpression; do what I said in the answer.  As for your second one, `^` means [bitwise-XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR), not raise-to-the-power-of.  To do a power operation, use `**`. This is all explained [on the wiki](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Operators).

Comment: @SagarJadhav If this answer was helpful to you, pls accept it and give the author the credit he deserves!

Answer (score 4):

you will have to write your own interpreter or find one that supports this kind of expressions.

The first part (the condition) can be evaluated by `NSPredicate`. For the second part (the calculation) you will need some math expression evaluation. Try this out https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser. Maybe you can do both with `DDMathParser` but i am not sure.